# Calculate the white pixel inside cv2.circle

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to implement identification of optic nerve glioma identification using python and openCV.

I need to do the following steps in order for me to classify optic nerve glioma successfully.

1. Find the brightest part of an image and put a circle on it using cv2.circle - **Done**
2. Calculate the white part on the image inside cv2.circle - **Needs help**

Here's my code for identifying the brightest part of the image

```
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (371, 371), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 371, (255, 0, 0), 2)

sought = [254,254,254]
amount = 0

for x in range(image.shape[0]):
    for y in range(image.shape[1]):
        b, g, r = image[x, y]
        if (b, g, r) == sought:
            amount += 1

print(amount)

image = imutils.resize(image, width=400)

# display the results of our newly improved method
cv2.imshow("Optic Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code above returns the following output

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is to identify the size of the white region of the image inside the cv2.circle.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you give a strict definition of "the white region"? Because the region is not really white, it's just brighter than the outer tissue on this image. But it's unclear where the region ends, so some definition is required.

Comment: I want to identify this whole bright region inside the circle

Comment: Please provide the input image.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you consider as "white", but here is one way to do the counting in Python/OpenCV. Simply read the image. Convert to grayscale. Threshold it at some level. Then just count the number of white pixels in the thresholded image.

If I use your output image for my input (after removing your white border):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('optic.png')

# convert to HSV and extract saturation channel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# count number of white pixels
count = np.sum(np.where(thresh == 255))
print("count =",count)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("optic_thresh.png", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Count of white pixels in threshold:

```
count = 1025729
```

Comment: is there a way to calculate what's inside the yellow circle only?

Comment: Manually draw a white circle on black background mask for the yellow circle. Then apply the mask to the thresholded image. Then count. Also please identify what how you define "white" inside what you call a yellow circle.

Comment: Also note that the white counted above already happens to fit inside the "yellow" circle, if I understand your "yellow" circle.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you consider as white and what you consider as the yellow circle. But here is another attempt using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert the input to the range 0 to 1 as 1D data
- Use kmeans clustering to reduce the number of colors and convert back to range 0 to 255 as 2D image
- Use inRange color thresholding to isolate the "yellow" area
- Clean it up with morphology and get the contour
- Get the minimum enclosing circle center and radius and bias the center a little
- Draw an unfilled white circle on the input
- Draw a white filled circle on a black background as a circle mask for the yellow area
- Convert the input to grayscale
- Threshold the grayscale image
- Apply the mask to the thresholded grayscale image
- Count the number of white pixels

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster

# read image
img = cv2.imread('optic.png')
h, w, c = img.shape

# convert to range 0 to 1
image = img.copy()/255

# reshape to 1D array
image_1d = image.reshape(h*w, c)

# do kmeans processing
kmeans_cluster = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=int(5))
kmeans_cluster.fit(image_1d)
cluster_centers = kmeans_cluster.cluster_centers_
cluster_labels = kmeans_cluster.labels_

# need to scale result back to range 0-255
newimage = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w, c)*255.0
newimage = newimage.astype('uint8')

# threshold brightest region
lowcolor = (150,180,230)
highcolor = (170,200,250)
thresh1 = cv2.inRange(newimage, lowcolor, highcolor)

# apply morphology open and close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

# get contour
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
c = cntrs[0]

# get enclosing circle and bias center, if desired, since it is slightly offset (or alternately, increase the radius)
bias = 5
center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
cx = int(round(center[0]))-bias
cy = int(round(center[1]))+bias
rr = int(round(radius))

# draw filled circle over black and also outline circle over input
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), rr, (255, 255, 255), -1)
circle = img.copy()
cv2.circle(circle, (cx,cy), rr, (255, 255, 255), 1)

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# threshold gray image
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply mask to thresh2
thresh2 = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh2, mask[:,:,0])

# count number of white pixels
count = np.sum(np.where(thresh2 == 255))
print("count =",count)

# write result to disk
#cv2.imwrite("optic_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("optic_kmeans.png", newimage)
cv2.imwrite("optic_thresh1.png", thresh1)
cv2.imwrite("optic_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("optic_circle.png", circle)
cv2.imwrite("optic_thresh2.png", thresh2)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("KMEANS", newimage)
cv2.imshow("THRESH1", thresh1)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("CIRCLE", circle)
cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
cv2.imshow("THRESH2", thresh2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

kmeans image:

[image]

inRange threshold image:

[image]

Circle on input:

[image]

Circle mask image:

[image]

Masked threshold image:

[image]

Count Results:

```
count = 443239
```